# can you have observations without choice in pylogit?

Tags: python

I have data in long format where lets say user 1 has 10 alternatives but did not chose any alternative so CHOICE is all 0. The problem i get is that when i include those users all model parameters are set 0. I do not understand why it is happening and could not find documentation either.